# Cant send image upload and use token bearer authentication with axios

Tags: authentication, vue.js, file-upload, http-headers, axios

```
let url = this.globalAPIBaseUrl + 'program/' + this.tmsID + '/updateposters/?posterType=' + imageType;
let j = [{
  posterType: imageType,
  url: imageUrl
}];
axios.patch(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  }
}, j, {
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    this.basic.status = 'Uploaded: ' + progressEvent.loaded + 'b of ' + progressEvent.total + 'b'
  }
}).then(response => (this.handleUploadComplete(response)));
```

before i put in the "headers" is worked fine, and when i use the same auth headers, but no "j" data variable elsewhere it also works fine.

Any advice, i'm kinda new here with axios. (this is in vue2.js btw)

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be the second parameter, and the third parameter is `config` object, where you can set `headers` and `onUploadProgress` callback

```
axios.patch(url, j, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  },
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    this.basic.status = 'Uploaded: ' + progressEvent.loaded + 'b of ' + progressEvent.total + 'b'
  }
}).then(response => (this.handleUploadComplete(response)));
```